# On Liberty by John Stuart Mill- please explain the meaning of following sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, meaning

*If all mankind minus one were of one opinion, and only one person were of the contrary opinion, mankind **would be no more justified** in silencing that one person, than he, if he had the power, would be justified in silencing mankind.*

Please help me understand the exact meaning being conveyed here.

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of 'no more'?

Comment: I am no more justified in killing you than you are in killing me (neither of us is justified at all in killing the other).

Comment: @michaelHarvey that's what I'm here for. In the context, is the one person justified in suppressing the world if he has the power? Or is he equally wrong?

Comment: Mill said neither the majority nor the minority is justified in silencing the other. What do you not understand?

Comment: I need support in settling an argument. I understood it perfectly well. Some of us come from places where English is a second or third language.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Or, logically, you're both equally justified in killing the other (although this is a truly unnatural interpretation of the sentence).

Comment: @PeterShor usually, the second thing is a zero-sized or negligible thing: I have no more chance of getting the manager's job than I have of becoming the next Pope.

Answer (score 3):

We use *no more … than*, or *not any more … than* to compare two things and say that the first thing is not greater than the second thing. *No more than* is more formal than *not any more than*.

Mill is saying that *the justification for the majority to silence the minority* (the first thing) is not any greater than *the justification for the minority to silence the majority* (the second thing).

[No more, not any more (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-more-not-any-more)